# How to derive the scale factor for special conformal transformation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

By definition a conformal transformation of the coordinates is an invertible mapping $x\rightarrow x'$ which leaves the metric invariant upto a scale factor:
\begin{equation}
 g_{\mu\nu}'(x') = \Lambda(x) g_{\mu\nu}(x)
\end{equation}

I am facing problems in deriving the scale factor for special conformal transformation (SCT). This transformation has the finite form given as: 
\begin{equation}
{x'}^{\mu} = \frac{x^{\mu}-b^{\mu}x^2}{1-2(b.x)+b^2x^2}
\end{equation}
I was trying to derive the scale factor for this transformation using the metric condition:
\begin{equation}
g_{\mu\nu}'(x') =\frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial {x'}^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\rho}{\partial {x'}^\nu}g_{\sigma\rho}= \Lambda(x) g_{\mu\nu}(x)
\end{equation}
I was not able to find out $\Lambda(x)$, however the final form of scale factor $\Lambda(x)$ is given in the book as:
\begin{equation}
\Lambda(x) = (1-2b.x + b^2x^2)^2
\end{equation}

Comment: And your question is? Plug the transformation in and look at the result! Please, also have a look at [our homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [our stance on check-my-work questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583).

Comment: Hello, welcome to SE. Could you try to clarify your question? What have you tried? Which point is causing trouble? I'm sure if you make it a little clearer, and say what you've tried, somebody might be able to help you.